# Primefaces dataTable selection records of composite key as rowKey

Tags: primefaces, selection

I have dataTable with selection, but when I select the records, the `selectedTeachers` variable is still empty. I guess it may be a `rowKey` problem which is `compositeKey`.

```
<p:dataTable var="item" value="#{uploadVo}" 
        rowKey="#{item.compositeKey}"
        selection="#{selectedTeachers}" rowIndexVar="index"
        id="gridItemName" rowSelectMode="checkbox" >
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple"/>
```

Entity code:

```
public Object[] getCompositeKey() {
    return new Object[] { this.batchNumb, this.schlnumb,this.schllocnid,
            this.schllevltypecode, this.schlsesstypecode, this.schlYear,
            this.schlnumbAdd, this.schllocnidAdd, this.schllevltypecodeAdd,
            this.schlsesstypecodeAdd, this.priIdTypeCode, this.priIdNo,
            this.issuePlaceCode, this.edbSubjCode, this.seq
    };
}
```

Comment: Why in the earth do you have a composite key this big? I'm afraid your data model has serious problems. Anyways to check the problem you can add a break-point into your entity get and see if it ever stops on it.